# How to create horizontal bar plot from nominal data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create a horizontal bar chart in python from nominal values, however, I cannot solve it by myself and I didn't find any good example on StackOverflow.

I would like to see changes in year's rotation of two seasons (duration, beginning, ending) from the year 1983 to the year 2019.

I have this dataframe and I thought about something like this:

```
DAY            SEASON       YEAR    DAY2
1983-12-27     Wet_Season   1983    27 Dec
1983-12-28     Wet_Season   1983    28 Dec
1983-12-29     Wet_Season   1983    29 Dec
 ....             ....       .....   ....
2019-04-28     Dry_Season   2019    28 Apr
```

---

```
p = pd.pivot_table(RSDF9, index='YEAR', columns='DAY2', values='SEASON', aggfunc='first')
sns.set_style("white")
fig2, ax2 = p.plot(kind='barh', width=0.85, figsize=(20, 10))

for ax2 in fig2.axes:
    mpl.pyplot.sca(ax2)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    loc = plticker.MultipleLocator(base=18)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
    ax2.legend(ncol=2, loc="upper right", frameon=True)
```

I expect horizontal bar plot for every year visualizing duration of a dry and a wet season however, I cannot use nominal data.

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: Right, so you will need to convert your strings to dates.

Comment: Is that only mistake? What about string type of Season column... Doesn't matter?

Comment: If you want to use pandas (`df.plot`) it might also be a problem yes. Matplotlib (`plt.plot(x,y)`) would be able to cope with that though you might want to change it to numeric values anyways to be able to sort it (is dry higher or lower than wet?).

Comment: Okey I will try it with new knowledge

Answer (score 1):

[DataMelt project](https://jwork.org/dmelt) has several examples implemented in Python/Java that show how to make charts with horizontal error bars. You  can look at [this blog](https://jwork.org/home/popularity_of_programs_for_data_science) that shows an example with this type of charts (+ code)